# DialogFragment open fragment with NavController

Tags: android

I have a `DialogFragment`. The NavController library not supported the `DialogFragment`, it supports only full-screen fragments.

I'm using `DialogFragment` with `show(fragmentManager,"")`, it works good, but inside the `DialogFragment` I can't get the "Navigation" instance. (Maybe because It doesn't start with NavController)

```
override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState)
    dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, null)
    viewModel = BaseViewModel.create(this)


    return AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(dialogView)
            .create()
}
```

I tried (in onCreateDialog, onActivityCreated)

```
Navigation.findNavController(view)
Navigation.findNavController(customView)
Navigation.findNavController(activity, R.id.thisFragmentId)
```

There is any option to load a new fragment with `NavController`?
If, not there is any alternative solution for this? I liked it because I could use `ViewModel` inside the `DialogFragment`.

Answer (score 4):

A few updates:

NavController library 2.0 and above supports DialogFragment destinations.

For example:

```
<dialog
        android:id="@+id/dialogFragmentScreen"
        android:name="com.x.y.DialogFragmentScreen"
        android:label="fragment_dialog"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_dialog" >
    <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dialogFragmentScreen_to_mainFragment"
            app:destination="@id/mainFragment"
            app:popUpTo="@id/mainFragment" />
</dialog>
```

Access the NavController:

findNavController(parentFragment!!.view!!)

Example:

findNavController(parentFragment!!.view!!).navigate(R.id.action_dialogFragmentScreen_to_mainFragment)

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. But I'm looking for a better solution.

```
val args = DirectionFragmentArgs.Builder()
       .setId(id)
       .build()
       .toBundle()

(activity as SingleActivity).navigation.navigate(R.id.directionFragmentId, args)
dismiss()
```